# How to dynamically resize list of images in responsive theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes, responsive-design, wordpress-theming

I am building my first responsive theme and this is the second of two issues I am having.

If you go to http://digitaldemo.net/landmark/ and look down at the bottom, there is a
horizontal list of images that is coded like this:

```
<ul>
<li>image 1</li>
<li>image 2</li>
<li>image 3</li>
<li>image 4</li>
<li>image 5</li>
</ul>
```

On screens 480px res or less, the list becomes 3 images instead of 5 but I would also like
to have the images resize like the masthead image does. I was able to get the masthead image to resize by adding `max-width:100%` but that didn't work for this list of images.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Cynthia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, by showing and hiding what's basically the same element on two different sizes, I think you are approaching the problem from a completely wrong side: from **usability** point of view (what if a user with a screen reader visits your site?), from **coding standards** point of view (bloated code, difficult to maintain, [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) and from a **SEO** perspective (duplicate content? Keyword stuffing?).

Second of all, you have two different elements using the same `id`. This shouldn't happen: [**the `id`s must be unique.**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

Third, getting to your problem: in order to resize an image dynamically through CSS you have to **set its dimensions through percentage**. In your case I would set the CSS to something like this:

```
#scroll.mobile ul {
    width: 100%;
}

#scroll.mobile li {
    width: 33%; /* You wanted three images per row, right? */
}

#scroll.mobile li img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

In this way your list element is going to take the whole window space, each list item only one third of it, and the images contained are going to be restricted to this one third of the window.